# Algorithm to match two histograms using only the x-axis variable

Tags: statistics, analysis

I have two histograms that should be very similar (typically a data/simulation plot). At first sight, the simulation distribution seems to have a shift difference with the data distribution. A naive attempt to correct it is to shift the simulation histogram such that the mean is matching the data distribution mean. The histograms are filled per event in a loop, so in each event, I fill (x-axis value + shift value) to correct the simulation. However, the agreement is only improved in the core of the distribution.

I was wondering if there is a smarter approach/algorithm to correct the simulation distribution to match data as much as possible, using only a correction that corrects the x-axis value (i.e. no event number scaling), it needs to be applied on the event level.

Many thanks!

Comment: Look up "histogram matching" which may do what you want.

Comment: Discussion questions are off topic for SO; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.